# Submit button does not read javascript file for validation and goes straight o my php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Hi, a newbie here on Stack overflow. Uhm my submit button does not read the java script file i created and goes straight to the php file instead of validating the input fields first on the java script file. I'm not quite sure what's wrong i've been stuck here for hour. 
I created the files separately. And i put the link to my javascript file at the end of my html file.

```
Here is my html code:




<!-- Add Student Modal-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="addUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <form class="form-horizontal" id="submitUserForm" action="action/createUser.php" method="POST">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="div-action pull pull-right" >
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div> <!-- /div-action -->     
            <h4 class="modal-title"> Add User</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body" style="max-height:650px; overflow:auto;">


            <div id="add-user-messages"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="full_name" name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
            </div> <!-- /form-group-->


            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
            </div> <!-- /form-group-->  

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" id="new_password" name="new_password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
            </div> <!-- /form-group-->  

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
            </div> <!-- /form-group-->  

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <select class="form-control" name="level" id="level">
                        <option value="">~~Level~~</option>
                        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                        <option value="User">User</option>

                      </select>
                    </div>                  
            </div> <!-- /form-group-->  

          </div> <!-- /modal-body -->

            <div class="modal-footer">

                  <button type="submit" id="createUserBtn" name="createUserBtn" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>

                  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="resetUserForm()"><i class="fa fa-eraser"></i> Reset Form</button>

            </div>
          <!-- /modal-footer -->
        </form>
         <!-- /.form -->
    </div>
    <!-- /modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /modal-dailog -->
</div>
<!-- / add modal -->
```

My Javascript Code:

```
$("#addUserModalBtn").unbind('click').bind('click', function() {

        $("#submitUserForm")[0].reset();    

        // remove text-error 
        $(".text-danger").remove();
        // remove from-group error
        $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

        $("#submitUserForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {

            // remove text-error 
        $(".text-danger").remove();
        // remove from-group error
        $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

            var full_name = $("#full_name").val();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var level = $("#level").val();
            var new_password = $("#new_password").val();
            var confirm_password = $("#confirm_password").val();

            const pasteBox = document.getElementById("#confirm_password");
              pasteBox.onpaste = e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
              };    

            if(full_name == "") {
                $("#full_name").after('<p class="text-danger">Full name field is required.</p>');
                $('#full_name').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            }   else {
                // remov error text field
                $("#full_name").find('.text-danger').remove();
                // success out for form 
                $("#full_name").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');     
            }   // /else

            if(username == "") {
                $("#username").after('<p class="text-danger">Username field is required.</p>');
                $('#username').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            }   else {
                // remov error text field
                $("#username").find('.text-danger').remove();
                // success out for form 
                $("#username").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');      
            }   // /else

            if(level == "") {
                $("#level").after('<p class="text-danger">Please select user level.</p>');
                $('#level').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            }   else {
                // remov error text field
                $("#level").find('.text-danger').remove();
                // success out for form 
                $("#level").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');     
            }   // /else

            if(new_password == "") {
                $("#new_password").after('<p class="text-danger">Password field is required.</p>');
                $('#new_password').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            }   else {
                // remov error text field
                $("#new_password").find('.text-danger').remove();
                // success out for form 
                $("#new_password").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');      
            }   // /else

            if(confirm_password == "") {
                $("#confirm_password").after('<p class="text-danger">Confirm password field is required.</p>');
                $('#confirm_password').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            }   else {
                // remov error text field
                $("#confirm_password").find('.text-danger').remove();
                // success out for form 
                $("#confirm_password").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');      
            }   // /else

            if(full_name && level && username && new_password) {

                var form = $(this);
                var formData = new FormData(this);

                $.ajax({
                    url : form.attr('action'),
                    type: form.attr('method'),
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:function(response) {

                        if(response.success == true) {
                            // submit loading button
                            $("#createUserBtn").button('reset');

                            $("#submitUserForm")[0].reset();

                            $("html, body, div.modal, div.modal-content, div.modal-body").animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 100);
                            setTimeout(function(){window.location = window.location}, 1000); 

                            // shows a successful message after operation
                            $('#add-user-messages').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+
                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
                    '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> '+ response.messages +
                  '</div>');

                            // remove the mesages
                  $(".alert-success").delay(500).show(10, function() {
                                $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
                                    $(this).remove();
                                });
                            }); // /.alert

                            // reload the manage student table
                            manageUsersTable.ajax.reload(null, true);

                            // remove text-error 
                            $(".text-danger").remove();
                            // remove from-group error
                            $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

                        } else if(response.success == false) {
                        // reload the manage member table 
                            manageUsersTable.ajax.reload(null, true);                       

                        // reset the form text
                        $("#submitUserForm")[0].reset();
                        $("html, body, div.modal, div.modal-content, div.modal-body").animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 100);
                        // remove the error text
                        $(".text-danger").remove();
                        // remove the form error
                        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

                $('#add-user-messages').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
            '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> '+ response.messages +
          '</div>');

                $(".alert-danger").delay(500).show(10, function() {
                            $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
                                $(this).remove();
                            });
                        }); // /.alert
                    }  // if

                    } // /success function
                }); // /ajax function
            }    // /if validation is ok                    

            return false;
        }); // /submit product form

    }); // /add product modal btn clicked
```

**And my PHP code:**

```
<?php   

require_once 'core.php';

$valid['success'] = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());


if($_POST) {    

    $full_name      = $_POST['full_name'];
    $username           = $_POST['username'];
    $new_password       = md5($_POST['new_password']);
    $confirm_password   = md5($_POST['confirm_password']);
    $level  = $_POST['level'];

    $status         = "0"; 


    if($new_password == $confirm_password) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(`full_name`, `username`, `password`, `level`, `status`) VALUES ('$full_name','$username','$new_password','$level', $status)";

        if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {

            $valid['success'] = true;
            $valid['messages'] = "Successfully added user account.";

        }else{

            return false;

        }

    }else{

            return false;

    }

    $connect->close();

    echo json_encode($valid);


} // /if $_POST

?>
```

Comment: As a side note, you need to revisit your password security: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: I do not see any element with id `addUserModalBtn`; does the function ever execute? Perhaps console browser/debugger is a good place to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes. The ID element is placed on top of my html page

Comment: <div class="div-action pull pull-right" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
    <button class="btn btn-info button1" id="addUserModalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addUserModal"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add User </button>
   </div> <!-- /div-action -->

Comment: Thank you. I will review my password security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of two solutions here:

### 1 Prevent default

You can prevent the submit button from executing the default event action. Instead of doing this:

```
$("#submitUserForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
```

Do it like this:

```
$('#submitUserForm').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //the rest of the submittion logic goes here
}
```

### 2 Button without the submit type

You actually don't have to create a button with the submit type, to send your form data (as you use $.ajax anyway). You can create a simple button with onClick event just like this:

```
<button onclick="submitForm()"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
```

And then the whole function that is under the

```
$("#submitUserForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
```

can be extracted to the new `submitForm` method

Comment: It worked!!!!! Thank you so much, saved my life. ♥
I cri. Have a good day/night!